# Makefile creating several mains as unit testing C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, makefile

I am quite new to makefiles but want to create a C++ project with some unit tests.

My project directory looks like this:

```
makefile
src/
    main.cpp
    file1.cpp
    file1.h
    file2.cpp
    file2.h
    ...
test/
    file1_test.cpp
    file2_test.cpp
    ...
```

I want the makefile to compile the program in src/ and also compile the programs in my test/ directory. Each *_test.cpp file contains a main() function. I have tried a lot of things but every time I try to compile I run into some new problem and it feels like it should be a quite easy task.

(Btw, I got inspired by this tutorial http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex28.html)

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT:**

My current makefile looks something like this. (I had to make some changes to fit this more general example)

```
CFLAGS =
LIBS =
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/
CC = g++ 
SOURCES=$(wildcard src/**/*.cpp src/*.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SOURCES))

TARGET=build/MyProgram

TEST_SRC=$(wildcard test/*_test.cpp)
TESTS=$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(TEST_SRC))
TESTS_PRG=$(patsubst %.cpp,%,$(TEST_SRC))
TESTS_OBJ=$(patsubst test/%_test.cpp,src/%.o,$(TEST_SRC))

all: $(TARGET) 

$(TARGET): build $(OBJECTS)
        g++ -o $(OBJECTS) $(CFLAS) $(LIBS)

build:
        @mkdir -p build
        @mkdir -p bin

.PHONY: tests
tests: $(TESTS_OBJ)                                                                                                                                        
        g++ $(TESTS_OBJ) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TESTS_PRG)                                                                                                         

clean:
        rm -rf build $(OBJECTS)                                                                                                                            
        rm -f tests/tests.log
        find . -name "*.gc*" -exec rm {} \;
        rm -rf `find . -name "*.dSYM" -print`
```

Comment: What does your current makefile look like?

Comment: You should post your makefile and consider using CMake and CTest as well.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are not using automake and make check?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your makefile as-is, after fixing the whitespace errors all over the place.

However, if I do that, I do not get the behaviour you claim: I get an error from g++ telling me that the second file1_test does not exist, as expected. To get the behaviour you claim, I have to remove the -o ${TESTS_PRG} at the end of 'tests' rule recipe line. The reason is the following:

You cannot specify multiple output files (-o) to generate multiple programs for one call to the compiler. If you remove the -o ${TESTS_PRG}, then the compiler tries to create one program from all the object files specified (${TESTS_OBJ}) and each of them probably have a main() routine, since they are supposed to be different programs. You need one call to the compiler per program.